# Javascript datepicker without using id

Tags: jquery, html, css

i use the datepicker code in following jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/27KTR/1/

it is working. Now i take the date picker to a id value like

```
 new datepickr('datepick2', {
        'dateFormat': 'd/m/y'
    });
```

but sometimes I need this datepicker without using any id value. How it possible.Please help me.

Comment: why are you using a crude mix of native javascript and jQuery

Comment: *without using any id value* would you be able to say in which input field you want to initialize the datepicker. or you mean to say you want to use class name instead of id?

Comment: I know what this guy's problem is, I think. I have struck the same issue. I have a group of radio fields with the same id, but different name attributes. I can apply the datepicker to the field based on its name, but when I select a date from the datepicker, it doesn't enter the date into the text field, probably because it wants to enter into the field based on ID instead of name

Answer (score 1):

For using datepicker with `id` try like

```
$("#id").datepicker({'dateFormat': 'd/m/y'});
```

Or if you want to use it by `class` try

```
$(".class").datepicker({'dateFormat': 'd/m/y'});
```

You can also use with tags like

```
$("input[type='text']").datepicker({'dateFormat': 'd/m/y'});
```

See my [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/27KTR/5/) that uses external resources like `jquery-ui.js` and try this way

And try the options from **http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/** you can go with the `date picker`

Comment: -1 : you are no way answering regards to the code he put in the fiddle.

Comment: You need to put the class name after `.`

Comment: @mithunsatheesh se the question plz..She is asking for other way to use datepicker otherthan id

Comment: @Parvathiiiii : it wont work because you are not using jquery date picker. the js code you are using expects id while initailizing the datepicker object that code has be modified.

Comment: @Gautam3164 : did you any way mention to use jquery or jquery ui to get this datepicker working and remove the native code she is using?

Comment: @Gautam3164 : that fiddle in reference dont even have jquery or jquery ui included. then how could you give a snippet like this without mentioning anything?

Comment: @mithunsatheesh what i didnt mentioned..??tell me ...I clearly told to try like $("#id").datepicker({'dateFormat': 'd/m/y'}); and other...Dont argue.try to answer it.You done with down right...??So now time to ans it..GoodLuck

Comment: @Gautam3164: actually i want to generate a datepicker with less size. So i am not using any ui. only use jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Comment: Yeh 2min I will give u the fiddle

Comment: @Parvathiiiii see my edited answer.And also see the external sources I have added

Comment: is that in the same jsfidle gautam

Comment: @Gautam3164: edit your question to say you need jquery and jquery ui for this and i will remove my downvote. else your answer doesnt make sense. Also regarding the answer, i will try to figure out and make the native js code rather than suggesting a full js library plus a ui framework for this task.

Comment: @Parvathiiiiiiiiii Its new fiddle that I have created...Remove all your code and add this with the external sources

Comment: click on that DEMO link

Comment: @Gautam3164: r u putting jquery datepicker ui??

Comment: @Parvathiiiii yes Iam

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I missunderstood the question. You can reduce the size of the calendar by updating the font size:

http://jsfiddle.net/27KTR/8/

`font-size:.5em`

I've set it to .5em but you can increase or decrease it as needed

As long as you can select an input field or a span you

Here's an example with a div using an id:http://jsfiddle.net/27KTR/8/

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inlinefont-size:.5em

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });

<scritp>
```

more about jQuery selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/